# Надо ли писать два двоеточия перед std?

Tags: c++

Некоторые авторы используют два двоеточия `::` перед неймспейсом `std`, например:

```
auto v = ::std::vector<int>(42);
::std::cout << "Hello, World!" << ::std::endl;
```

Знаю, что это указывает на использование идентификаторов из глобального скопа, но разве идентификатор `std` используют как-то иначе (исключая программистские шутки)?

Не будет ли это оверстраховкой, сродни, к примеру, проверке, что `false` это `false`, а не переопределенный `#define` (добавлением `#undef false`)?

Answer (score 7):

Формально спецификация языка С++ не содержит прямого запрета на использование идентификатора `std` в качестве имени какой-то вложенной сущности, создающей свою область видимости.

При желании вы можете создать свой namespace `vasya::std`

```
namespace vasya {
  namespace std {
    ...
  }

  void foo() {
    // Здесь `std` и `::std` неэквивалентны
  }
}
```

Т.е. формально возможно существование контекста, в котором `::std` и `std` означают разные вещи.

Однако без явной необходимости такое избыточное устранение неоднозначности через безусловное приписывание `::` перед `std` выглядит выражено избыточным. Это что-то вроде назойливого указания `this->` всякий раз при обращении к члену класса. Если вы придерживаетесь некоторого стиля, требующего постоянного `::std` и/или постоянного `this->`, то это - ваше право. Но такой стиль всегда будет очень нишевым.

Comment: Это значит, что в библиотеке лучше использовать `::std`?

Answer (score 6):

Можно каждый раз обьяснять шоферу, что машину ремонтируют в автомастерской,
а не в больнице, а  лучше  лишный раз не засорять эфир.

Если кто то не поймет, что `std::vector` это STL контейнер, 
то тогда он точно не поймет, что означает
`::std::vector<::std::string>`  ну и как страховка это выглядит
немного смешно.

Лично я, кроме эффективности и всего прочего,
обращаю внимание на читабельность того, что пишу
(это восе не означает, что я пишу идеально...), т.е. стараюсь не засорять 
страницу лишными символами, а эфир лишными словами...

Это дело вкуса..

Если я пишу код, где из namespace std фигурируют только `vector` и `cout`,
то `using namespace std;` будет только излишным засорением глобального 
пространства,а вот `using std::vector;  using std::cout;` будет самое то...

Answer (score 6):

*tl;dr;* Явное указание `::` перед `std` позволяет избежать некоторых дефектов и улучшает поддерживаемость кода.

Я вот как раз из "некоторых авторов". Сразу скажу, что `::` использую для *всех* идентификаторов из глобального пространства имен. И причин делать исключение для `std` я не вижу. Дело в том, что пренебрегая `::` перед `std` программист сразу начинает делать массу шатких предположений:

- Написав `std::` я обращаюсь к коду стандартной библиотеки;

  Код запросто может быть откуда-то еще. Объявлять в пространстве `std` собственные специализации для шаблонов не только можно, но и зачастую нужно. Обычная ситуация во множестве проектов.
- Ну Ок, написав `std::` я обращаюсь либо непосредственно к коду стандартной библиотеки, либо к коду, соответствующему спецификациям стандартной библиотеки;

  Кто-нибудь запросто может объявить у себя вложенное пространство имен `std` и соответствующие классы. Например написать классы, поддержка которых еще не реализована в текущей версии компилятора. Такое можно увидеть, когда приходится долго сидеть со старым компилятором или при обратном портировании.
- Ладно, написав `std::` я обращаюсь либо непосредственно к коду стандартной библиотеки, либо к коду, соответствующему спецификациям стандартной библиотеки, либо к коду, который делает то же самое, что должен был бы делать соответствующий кусок стандартной библиотеки;

  Нет никаких причин, по которым этот код не мог бы служить для совершенно иных целей. Как вариант:

```cpp
// где-то в инклюдах
namespace goodCompany {
/// <summary>Поддерживаемые стандартные контейнеры</summary>
enum class std { vector, list ...

// где-то в коде
namespace goodCompany {
void vdfsd(void)
{
    std::vector<int> items; // это тыква, а никакой ни STL контейнер
}
```

- Но у нас-то в кодовой базе таких безобразий нет, чтим `std`, как священную корову, так что написав `std::` я точно обращаюсь к коду стандартной библиотеки;

  Сегодня нет, но кто сможет поручится, что их не будет чрез 5 лет? А если `std::` написано внутри макроса (или `.inl` файла), то содержимое вашей кодовой базы совсем не важно, так как макрос может быть развернут внутри другой кодовой базы.

Закончу цитатой из Стругацких (Страна багровых туч):

> Мы не можем себе позволить дать Венере хотя бы один, самый маленький шанс против нас. Даже недоеденный вами кусок телятины…

Comment: Как `::std` защитит от пользовательского `namespace std`, не заключённого ни в какие другие пространства имён?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan В том вопросе запись `::std::vector` вполне бы давала такую гарантию. Действия вида `#define vector Vector` прямо запрещены в стандарте (20.5.4.3.2 [macro.names]). Написание в глобальном пространстве std самопальных классов, классов, замещающих стандартные (или специализаций, не соответствующих требованиям к классу) является неопределенным поведением. Вообще тут я рассматриваю корректный код, без шуток и злоупотреблений препроцессором. Под "внутри макроса" я подразумеваю `#define MyContainer ::std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @Arhad Содержимое глобального пространства `std` и возможности пользователя по написанию кода внутри него регламентируются стандартом. Если кто-то напишет свой некомфорный `::std::vector`, то это будет неопределенным поведением, а я тут рассматриваю ситуацию, когда прочий код корректен.

Answer (score 2):

В случае `std` явное указание на отсчёт от глобального пространства имён действительно избыточно.

Однако в случае других пространств имён и обильного использования библиотек лучше перестраховаться, чтобы не словить коллизию каких-нибудь тривиально названных `namespace`.

> Не будет ли это оверстраховкой, сродни, к примеру, проверке, что false это false, а не переопределенный #define

В своё время (когда C++ ещё не был стандартизирован) это было не «оверстраховкой», а жизненной необходимостью. Да и на стыке Си и C++ со стороны первого могут «вылезти» подобного рода макроопределения.