# Ошибка при вычислении остатка при делении

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь вычислить остаток от деления:

```
double *x, *y;
int p = 2;
x[k] = y[k] % p;
```

При вычислении выдает:

> выражение должно относиться к целочисленному типу или типу перечисления без области видимости.

Что не так?

Comment: `y` у вас какой тип имеет?

Comment: И откуда берётся необъявленное k?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Встроенный оператор `%` работает только для целочисленных типов. Для получения остатка от деления чисел с плавающей точкой следует использовать функцию [`fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod):

```
x[k] = ::std::fmod(y[k], static_cast<double>(p));
```

Comment: `::std` это для особо параноидальных ситуаций?

Comment: @alexolut [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762601/Надо-ли-писать-два-двоеточия-перед-std/762754#762754](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762601/Надо-ли-писать-два-двоеточия-перед-std/762754#762754)

Comment: А разве не будет выполнено автоматическое повышение int до double при вызове fmod?

Comment: @Mikhailo Будет, но зачем же полагаться на неявные преобразования.

Answer (score 4):

У вас значение `y[k]` имеет тип `double`, а в C++ получение остатка `%` - операция сугубо целочисленная.

Ибо сказано в 5.6.2: *операнды операции % должны иметь целочисленный тип или перечислимый тип без области действия*...

Comment: спасибо)а можно чтобы с double работал?

Comment: Нельзя. Но можно посмотреть на функцию [`fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod).