# Как вернуть std::unique_ptr из контейнера

Tags: c++, c++17, контейнеры, unique-ptr

У меня есть stl или boost контейнер хранящий  std::unique_ptr. Как известно  std::unique_ptr поддерживают только move симатику в связи с чем возникает вопрос, как вернуть перемещённый ранее в контейнер указатель?

```
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

...

using boost::circular_buffer;

...

int main() {
    circular_buffer<unique_ptr<int>> cb(10);
    std::mutex mut;
    std::future async = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() -> void {
        while (true) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
            if (!cb.empty()) {
                unique_ptr<int> tmp = cb.back(); // Как тут сделать так что бы был вызван move конструктор?                                 
                cout << "[" << *tmp << "]";
                cb.pop_back();                               
            }
        }
        1 + 1;
    });
    while (true) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        unique_ptr<int> tmp = std::make_unique<int>(0);
        cin >> *tmp;
        cb.push_front(std::move(tmp));
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаточно выполнить move:

```
::std::unique_ptr<int> tmp{::std::move(cb.back())};
```

Comment: Спасибо. Зачем некоторые программисты ставят двоеточие перед пространство имён? Ради читабельности или это влияет на что-то ещё?

Comment: @mrFieldy [Надо ли писать два двоеточия перед std?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762601/Надо-ли-писать-два-двоеточия-перед-std/762754#762754).