# Определить возвращаемый тип перегруженной функции в шаблоне

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

У меня возникает проблема с определением типа возвращаемого значения перегруженной функции внутри шаблона. Возвращаемый тип зависит от параметра, который передается в шаблон. Сразу приведу минимальный рабочий пример:

```cpp
#include <vector>

// У меня есть несколько типов
struct a { a() {} };
struct b { b() {} };
struct c { c() {} };

// И одна функция, перегруженная с разными входными и выходными параметрами
a foo(b) { return a(); }
b foo(c) { return b(); }
c foo(a) { return c(); }

// Проблема: как определить C автоматически?
template<class T, class C>
std::vector<C> fooMas(const std::vector<T>& mas) {
    std::vector<C> result;
    for (auto i : mas)
        result.push_back(foo(i));
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<a> amas(5, a());
    std::vector<c> cmas = fooMas<a, c>(amas);
    //std::vector<c> cmas = fooMas(amas); // Здесь возникает ошибка
}
```

Вручную такое писать бы не хотелось, потому что у меня много типов, и много перегруженных функций, и все их надо перевести на такое обращение с массивом. Хотелось бы это автоматизировать с помощью вышеописанного шаблона, но не представляю как. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template<typename T> auto // возвращаемый тип выводится из return result
fooMas(::std::vector<T> const & mas)
{
    ::std::vector<decltype(foo(mas.front()))> result{}; // выводим из результата функции
    for(auto const & i : mas)
    {
        result.emplace_back(foo(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, впервые вижу такую вещь как decltype.

Comment: а зачем двоеточие перед стд? `::std::vector`

Comment: @goldstar_labs [Надо ли писать два двоеточия перед std?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762601/Надо-ли-писать-два-двоеточия-перед-std/762754#762754)

Comment: спасибо) даже тут коварный с++ норовит цапнуть за ногу

Comment: @VTT, для определения возвращаемого типа лучше использовать ```decltype```.