# Запись текста в std::string дважды. С++

Tags: c++

Допустим у меня есть `std::string str`. Хочу ввести с клавиатуры текст, который скопируется в `str`. Можно через `std::getline(std::cin, str)`. А как снова что нибудь ввести с клавиатуры и это что-то также скопируется в `str` не создавая при этом других `std::string str1` (То есть не создавая временную переменную  `std::string str1` в которой будет текст, который я ввел во второй раз, а потом `str += str1`). Например я ввел `Первая` в командной строке нажал `Enter` , потом ввел `строка` и `std::cout << str` выведет мне `Первая строка`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str); // Ввожу  `первая`
    std::cout << "\n" << str << "\n"; // выведет `первая`
    std::getline(std::cin, str);// Ввожу `строка`
    std::cout << "\n" << str << '\n';// Вывдет `строка`
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну точно также... Непонятно, в чем у вас затруднение...

Comment: Ну я пробовал. Метод std::getline() перезаписывает то, что находится внутри `str`. Например я ввел `первая` и `std::cout << str` выведет `первая`, потом снова введу , например `вторая` ,и `std::cout << str` выведет не `перваястрока` , а просто `строка`.

Comment: @VTT Или вы имели ввиду что-то другое?

Answer (score 1):

Тогда можно реализовать самопальную getline, неперезаписывающую строки:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

::std::istream &
my_getline(::std::istream & input, ::std::string & str)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        auto const c{::std::cin.get()};
        if(::std::cin.good() && ('\n' != c))
        {
            str.push_back(static_cast<char>(c));
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }   
    }
    return input;
}

int main()
{
    ::std::string str;
    my_getline(::std::cin, str);
    ::std::cout << str << "\n"; // выведет `первая`
    my_getline(::std::cin, str);
    ::std::cout << str << '\n';// Вывдет `перваястрока`
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Z2jKrLlqRNKtwxFK)

Comment: Можно два вопроса ? 1) Почему вы пишете оператор `::` перед `std::string` , `std::cin`, `std::istream`. 2) Как работает цикл `for (;;) {}`, до какого момента он будет работать ( не в вашем случае , а в общем )?

Comment: 2) это типа бесконечного цикла? @VTT

Comment: @Kaznachei 1) [Надо ли писать два двоеточия перед std?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762601/Надо-ли-писать-два-двоеточия-перед-std/762754#762754) 2) да это бесконечный цикл, записывается короче чем `while(true)` и не вызывает предупреждения некоторых компиляторов о том, что условие цикла не изменяется

Answer (score 0):

```
using std::string;
using It = std::istream_iterator<string>;
It first(std::cin), last();
string s;
while (std::cin) {
    s += *first++;
    s += ' ';
}

std::cout << s;
```