# Что будет эффективнее?

Tags: c++

Имеем мы 8 функций:

```
void Function1() {}
...
void Function8() {}
```

И есть у нас переменная char, в которой есть как раз 8 бит.
Если, к примеру, в ней записано 10001011, то мы должны выполнить Function1, Function5, Function7, Function8.
Так вот, что же будет эффективнее по ресурсам и занимаемой памяти?

1) 8 if'ов:

```
void CallFunctions(char val) {
if(val & 1) {
Function1();
}
...
if(val & 0x80) {
Function8();
}
}
```

2) Инициализировать массив с указателями на функции, размером в 256 элементов:

```
std::function<void()> *ptrs;
```

И вызывать каждую функцию по адресу val:

```
void CallFunctions(char val) {
ptrs[val]();
}
```

К примеру, по адресу ptrs[1] будет находиться функция, которая вызывает лишь Function1();
По адресу ptrs[3] уже будет находиться функция, которая вызывает Function1() и Function2() по очереди.
3) Ваш вариант.

Если второе, то как это сделать с минимальным выделением памяти?

Comment: Ваши `if`ы делают не то, что вы думаете. `(x ^ y) == y` всегда означает то же, что и `x == 0`. Правильно - `if (val & 0x80)` и т. п.

Comment: Ох, точно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3) сделать массив с 8 указателями и итеративно проходиться по нему:

```
using t_Method = void (void);
using t_Methods = ::std::array<t_Method *, 8>;

t_Methods const methods{&Function1, …};
auto flags{0b10001011u};
auto method_index{0u};
while(0u != flags)
{
   if(0u != (flags bitand 1u))
   {
       ::std::invoke(methods[method_index]);
   }
   flags >>= 1u;
   ++method_index;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YkjvcUOhs6vj7Dlc)

Comment: Спасибо! Только возник ещё один вопрос - для чего нужно ставить :: перед std?

Comment: @Alleksh_ [Надо ли писать два двоеточия перед std?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762601/Надо-ли-писать-два-двоеточия-перед-std/762754#762754). Еще в качестве условия остановки можно использовать равенство оставшихся флагов нулю.

Comment: Обилие лишних букв (в т.ч. в лишних сущностях) еще один существенный минус в C++

Comment: @VTT мне кажется проще не ставить лишние двоеточия, чем объяснять под каждым ответом :)