# C++, namespace и оператор расширения видимости

Tags: c++, namespace

Подскажите, что означает оператор расширения области видимости, который ставится перед идентификатором?

Например, в `Google Tests` я встречаю:

```
::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
```

Какую функцию несет оператор `::`, который ставится перед `testing`?

Comment: Указывает глобальное пространство имен.

Comment: @Harry, в ответы.

Comment: По теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762601/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-std

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::`, перед которым нет никакого имени - указывает глобальное пространство имен.