# Использование concept'ов с несколькими type-параметрами

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, concept

Не могу понять, как и можно ли вообще использовать концепты типа:

```
template <typename Type1, typename Type2>
concept StdByteContainer =
    (std::same_as<Type1,std::remove_cvref_t<std::basic_string<Type2>>>
        || std::same_as<Type1,std::remove_cvref_t<std::vector<Type2>>>
        || std::same_as<Type1,std::remove_cvref_t<std::list<Type2>>>
        || std::same_as<Type1,std::remove_cvref_t<std::deque<Type2>>>
        || std::same_as<Type1,std::remove_cvref_t<std::set<Type2>>>)
    && (std::same_as<Type2,std::byte>
        || (std::is_integral_v<Type2> && sizeof(Type2)==1));
```

Пытался писать так:

```
template <StdByteContainer Type1<Type2>>
void function(const Type1<Type2>& container);
```

Так:

```
template <StdByteContainer Type1, StdByteContainer Type2>
void function(const Type1<Type2>& container);
```

Так:

```
template <StdByteContainer Type1, Type2>
void function(const Type1<Type2>& container);
```

Так:

```
template <StdByteContainer Type1 Type2>
void function(const Type1<Type2>& container);
```

Никак не выходит, статический анализатор пишет:

```
error: 'StdByteContainer' requires more than 1 template argument
```

Так вообще можно писать, или такие концепты в принципе недопустимы? Хотя объявление концепта парсер пропустил, посчитав валидным... Если что, использую `GCC-10`.

Comment: Может для разнообразия попробовать передать в концепт два параметра?

Comment: @user7860670, Каким образом? Я уже наизвращался по всякому, и в сети искал. Не знаю как.

Comment: Вы лучше напишите, чего вы тут хотите добиться. Откуда там берутся два типа, когда в функцию передается std::span?

Comment: @user7860670, два, потому что один внутри другого. Т.е. передается шаблонный класс, а именно один из стандартных контейнеров, который внутри себя содержит байты. Вообще, я их столько добавил просто для эксперимента =)

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. У вас же передается ::std::span... Приведите лучше пример с параметром тип которого должен подходить, и пример с типом, которой не должен подходить.

Comment: @user7860670, `std::string`, `std::vector<std::byte>`, `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`, `std::deque<std::byte>`, `std::deque<std::uint8_t>` должны проходить, например.

Comment: Они никак не смогут подходить, так как тип аргумента функции - std::span< что-то >

Comment: @user7860670, ну так поэтому и должно быть `std::span<std::vector<std::byte>>`, например.

Comment: Я кажется понял свой косяк)) Я span не так использую)))

Comment: Но все равно интересно, гипотетически, если такой случай будет, то как использовать то?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118083/discussion-between-megorit-and-user7860670).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо идея была, чтобы один параметр был типом контейнера, а другой - типом объектов, хранящихся в этом контейнере. Однако мне это представляется избыточным. Сделал такой пример с одним параметром шаблона и проверкой через зависимые типы.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <span>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename x_Container>
concept StdByteContainer = 
    (
        ::std::same_as
        <
            ::std::basic_string<typename x_Container::value_type, typename x_Container::allocator_type>
        ,   ::std::remove_cvref_t<x_Container>
        >
        or
        ::std::same_as
        <
            ::std::vector<typename x_Container::value_type, typename x_Container::allocator_type>
        ,   ::std::remove_cvref_t<x_Container>
        >
        // ...
    )
    and
    ::std::is_integral_v<typename x_Container::value_type>
    and
    (sizeof(typename x_Container::value_type) == 1);

//requires
//{
//    typename x_Container::velue_type;
//};

template <StdByteContainer x_Container>
void checksum(std::span<x_Container> span) {}

int main()
{
    ::std::vector<::std::vector<char>> items{{},{}};
    checksum(::std::span<::std::vector<char>>{items.begin(), items.end()});
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/h5E1je

Comment: Спасибо, идея понятна. Нужно юзать типы контейнеров, а сам концепт делать с одним типом. Однако вопрос о том,  как использовать концепт с несколькими параметрами типов остается открытым =))

Comment: А зачем для `std` scope resolution opreator использовать?

Comment: @megorit Ну вот `::std::same_as` - это концепт с двумя параметрами. [Надо ли писать два двоеточия перед std?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762601/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-std/762754#762754)