# Как задать соответствие числа и типа данных C++?

Tags: c++

От внешнего источника в двоичном виде приходят данные, как можно в зависимости от кода типа данных получать переменную определёного типа, возможно ли это сделать более обобщённо без множества условий? Ниже привожу пример текущей реализации.

```
// Классы, реализующие обработку сообщений
class MsgType1;
class MsgType2;
class MsgType3;
class MsgType4;

enum class MsgCode {
  Type1,
  Type2,
  Type3,
  Type4
};

void data_reseive(int msg_type, void* msg_data) {
  MsgCode c = static_cast<MsgCode>(msg_type);
  switch (c) {
  case MsgCode::Type1:
  {
    MsgType1 msg;
    msg.process(msg_data);
    break;
  }
  case MsgCode::Type2:
  {
    MsgType2 msg;
    msg.process(msg_data);
    break;
  }
  case MsgCode::Type3:
  {
    MsgType3 msg;
    msg.process(msg_data);
    break;
  }
  case MsgCode::Type4:
  {
    MsgType4 msg;
    msg.process(msg_data);
    break;
  }
  }
}

// Пример с использованием полиморфизма

class MsgTypeBase {
  public:
  virtual void process(void* data) = 0;
  virtual bool operator==(MsgCode code) = 0;
};

template<MsgCode C>
class MsgTypeContBase: MsgTypeBase {
  public:
  bool operator==(MsgCode code) {
    return static_cast<int>(C) == static_cast<int>(code);
  }
};

class MsgTypeCont1: public MsgTypeBase<MsgCode::Type1> {
  public:
  void process(void* data) {
    MsgType1 msg;
    msg.process(data);
  }
};

class MsgTypeCont2: public MsgTypeBase<MsgCode::Type2> {
  public:
  void process(void* data) {
    MsgType2 msg;
    msg.process(msg_data);
  }
};

class MsgTypeCont3: public MsgTypeBase<MsgCode::Type3> {
  public:
  void process(void* data) {
    MsgType3 msg;
    msg.process(msg_data);
  }
};

class MsgTypeCont4: public MsgTypeBase<MsgCode::Type4> {
  public:
  void process(void* data) {
    MsgType4 msg;
    msg.process(msg_data);
  }
};

std::vector<MsgTypeBase*> m_list;

void init() {
  m_list.push_back(new MsgTypeCont1());
  m_list.push_back(new MsgTypeCont2());
  m_list.push_back(new MsgTypeCont3());
  m_list.push_back(new MsgTypeCont4());
}

void data_reseive(int msg_type, void* msg_data) {
  MsgCode c = static_cast<MsgCode>(msg_type);
  for (auto m: m_list) {
    if (*m == c) {
      m->process(msg_data);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: для красоты первого этапа можно в switch это завернуть. Но потом похоже, что все эти конструкторы одинаковые, может там и один класс нужен*

Comment: @KoVadim типы сообщений MsgType1, MsgType2, MsgType3, MsgType4 разные и каждый из них инкупсулирует свои методы обработки данных, не использую switch потому что он не позволяет объявлять переменную внутри себя, нужно делать блоки кода.

Comment: Вам нельзя поставить скобочки фигурные?  Хотя если Ваш код выглядит именно так, как он показан, то может просто сделать свои функции для process_msg1, process_msg2 и так далее, а потом просто их сохранить в массив/мапу. и код будет состоять буквально с пары строк.

Comment: @KoVadim, можно и switch, не принципиально, но я бы хотел избавиться от такого перебора значений

Answer (score 3):

Если идентификаторы идут подряд, то можно сделать диспечеризацию по списку типов, если нет (или если их слишком много для перебора) - то по аналогии через таблицу соответствия:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

using
t_MsgCode = int;

template
<
    typename x_Msg
>
void
Process
(
    void * const data
);

template
<
    typename x_MsgsTuple
,   typename x_IdsSequence = void
>
struct
t_Dispatcher;

template
<
    typename... x_Msgs
,   t_MsgCode... x_indexes
>
struct
t_Dispatcher<::std::tuple<x_Msgs...>, ::std::integer_sequence<t_MsgCode, x_indexes...>> final
{
    static void
    Dispatch
    (
        t_MsgCode const code
    ,   void * const p_data
    )
    {
        (((code == x_indexes) ? Process<x_Msgs>(p_data) : void()), ...);
    }
};

template
<
    typename... x_Msgs
>
struct
t_Dispatcher<::std::tuple<x_Msgs...>, void> final
{
    static void
    Dispatch
    (
        t_MsgCode const code
    ,   void * const p_data
    )
    {
        using
        t_IdsSequence = ::std::make_integer_sequence
        <
            t_MsgCode
        ,   static_cast<t_MsgCode>(sizeof...(x_Msgs))
        >;

        t_Dispatcher<::std::tuple<x_Msgs...>, t_IdsSequence>::Dispatch(code, p_data);
    }
};

struct
t_FirstMsg {};

struct
t_SecondMsg {};

struct
t_ThirdMsg {};

using
t_Msgs = ::std::tuple<t_FirstMsg, t_SecondMsg, t_ThirdMsg>;

void
Receive_Data
(
    t_MsgCode const code
,   void * const p_data
)
{
    t_Dispatcher<t_Msgs>::Dispatch(code, p_data);
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrS6dSV9ABk8tTADlnACNMYhAANl4AB1QhQnNaO0cXN1IYuLM6Hz9ApxCwyKNME0zaBgJmYgIk51cATiKShPLKgmyA4NCQAFYGoQqqmpS%2BgbbfDryu3oBKI1QHYmQOKR0AZl9kRywAak1VmwIATyjMAH0CYmZCIT3sTRkAQTWNrcxd/YIHKPZb%2B6ftda0TYOHZ7GwOMysQiHX6PP4OOLqP4EU4AWSEwDsoNWABFtr4CHt9HDHgRME5vswyX8wX9tvTtkcTrRmE43uI0Riaas7o8AG6oPDoP6iYioJZCG6PCB0hkCoXbABU2zQtH623QVOYf2mRJppPJlOpcP2svpTKsrPZnOAQgAKl8fo9SAyLSy2dsOQBJdBCBiYACODisS3eePlwpNvIe/WIDlMyNOOLwQiiVOQCFCepJDzJFNUxqepseDMZx0tbIAdNXPTapQ8XeabVjMNXK7XfFhxJh67CYxd44TSUmU2mCBms/sQCB%2Buhp59vpgwRz0ba27cXdPZ9OCZhgKFTiIgyGlx9mxhMC6OZ3MN2hOuebdtlRfGwaQB2YkPUv9Kl4ZDbBGZrbMmqbpggwEyiWpauueOyquqaBYMBjaAYK6BKiqdDqlEpyahUwG6tB9KaJ%2BwGllAEBIW8ew4rRHbWLePbTO8ABi2yiuKPY3PsK4Yjx2AQLh%2BHMCxIBoUKEDTLM2xtrqqxfqWpF0XC750Qp%2Bq5oaBZLiaNjAW6VptrWq69o%2BjyxoOiagWOE7EGCW4EHOIALj8vF1g%2B2AukBPLPq%2BrAfopDK/mYAFAcRIGjuBkHkbBq4tlhaoEFhyERahEaYQhyXCVqhHAaRQUwdsCK%2BMAsVNj6fqBsGQI0bi2yOc5TjMAA1mcu77sQh7VSe5XvPpEVFU28UXn1qEhf%2BpwsP0YIoiNyE8hAcQAF6YKgVBthAfG2tJfW/BpOZDYyI5geOmb2VOM5OfOjqnjY233tWG7HZV/rHrVtzTjZ4FUReLo5RU8mFbsakfupX5/JZCbDqxeDEP0q4g/ooMHU8FkDtDuanP6qroIjBXKdmaP9nGmMonaCBw3jGJI4TqPwoiZXDqZYYNVdzmuXdKKw/DBCri6KI43Q1PAALpwU1Tq77RD/LoX8ABKmBLHgfJnDiuXSgZcFvFlKW6Q2croZl2HZXhGsPERTxkRFKLfWdk4HHWn0gHbGa/Vg/1m4DROE48UizKw0jdPIriyPIqDSPpegGNsQjzIsNEApw8gENIcjSaQLU9DIKjSNwIdp%2BH0jyEIIA56nYezHAsAwIgKCoBSeDsGQFC/Y3zcgMAnDd3wTdkvDlBBIXpBBK%2BxCHNIyekGgThsvQADytCsBPYekFgzXqOww/4MQStmKrper0xyAQssU%2B7oHq9QkElzjy2w8XHgTiT/7fB0IwLBbzwb%2BCCIEjD0odwqh1AoAMAYFQeAgil0gLMVAURSiHwALSINnLRLQ0c9DaBkNsRBAB1NgrAcG4NvBcZgRDVSq3hgkIhJxNT0H/CXYoe8EiWGsEMVw7hPDtFyPkZQ6R4h0HYXw2IAjaDcM6GEdwxhmF0BaIMewtRlDSNMM0UY4jJiSKMKMIRUi1HjB4V0Tgsw44LCWFwAOQcC6rwjlIcQAAOcIiDIjbGAMgAC3dKycG2BAXAhASC7CTi6Ow7dQgBNWEY7YUd9B6BToXDOWdug50vvnUgz9EmkFDnIUgNiS5l1IBXdOpBq513mAQKIEJyCUBnlEJuhiPD4CIJo/gH82AcG/s04QYhJCrwAO6XCiHE3OUhg4ZOHjY%2BeEJynJXWp6BxTjuAuLcdsDxXiIDBJqc3MJRjYmV1mJmZgWAwhSSGSktJOdMlFykLk8ucTZgJKSdIVYVisk5PybcoZ2hnmXJ2enWYlC4gWG4EAA%3D)

Comment: Спасибо, только с C++20 будет работать?

Comment: С 17 тоже будет, с более старыми - после небольших модификаций диспатчер должен будет работать рекурсивно.

Comment: Хороший ответ, хоть и немного замудрёный с учётом того, что автор просил без множества усилий)

Но форматирование с этими пробелами и абзацами между фигурных скобок - просто отвратительно.

Comment: @ГлебТруфанов https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtOQd.jpg

Comment: @user7860670, просто не используйте такой код стайл, это убивает глаза и создаёт впечатление, будто код намеренно усложнён..Будто бы из stl стилистику взяли..

Comment: посмотрел на код. давно я не видел, что бы перед std ставили двоеточие...

Comment: @KoVadim https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762601/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-std/762754#762754

Comment: @ГлебТруфанов, вы считаете правильным указывать человеку, какой он должен использовать code style? O_o. Это, как бы, личное дело каждого. Хотя мне тоже не нравится :)

Comment: @user7860670 - это ужас  и параноя. А если что то написал у себя в коде enum std, то гораздо легче дать такому человеку по рукам - такой код может много сломать.

Comment: @KoVadim Дублируя тот мой ответ, замечу, что в С++ идентификатор std сам по себе не является каким-то зарезервированным и ни малейших оснований предъявлять использующему этот идентификатор претензии у вас быть не может. А насчет "проще дать такому человеку по рукам" - это откровенное самодурство, и такой подход выглядит особенно бестолковым, когда "такой человек" оказывается соавтором стандарта, сторонней библиотеки или просто более квалифицированным коллегой.

Comment: @eanmos А этот code style выработан совсем не по принципу нравится / не нравится... Мне вообще-то FORTH нравится.

Comment: Автор стандартам пишет такий код, который ломает код... Ну-ну. Или это автор auto_ptr?

Answer (score 2):

Написал свой вариант.

```
// Функции, реализующие обработку сообщений
// имена могут быть любые
void process_msg1(void* data) {}
void process_msg2(void* data) {}
void process_msg3(void* data) {}
void process_msg4(void* data) {}

// сигнатура осталась старой
void data_reseive(int msg_type, void* msg_data) {
    // эта мапа помечена static, что бы один раз инициализировать
    static std::map<int, void(*)(void* data)> trans = 
    {
      // привязываем идекс-обработчик
      {1, &process_msg1},
      {2, &process_msg2},
      {3, &process_msg3},
      {4, &process_msg4}
    };

  auto f = trans.find(msg_type);
  if (f == trans.end()) {
      // ой, ничего не найдено
      return;
  }
  // собственно вызываем обработку.
  f->second(msg_data);
}
```

Если индексы идет подряд, можно использовать массив. Это даст чуточку ускорения. Мапу с функции можно при желании вынести. А вообще при желании можно там вставить лямбды, но это на любителя

Comment: Массив для таблицы стоит использовать, даже если индексы идут не подряд. Помимо ускорения доступа, это позволит также избавится от динамической инициализации.

Comment: можно, если индексы достаточно близко расположены. Но мы не знаем, как там точно реализовано.

Comment: можно и когда индексы разбросаны абы как, сортированный или разряженный массив еще никто не отменял

Answer (score 1):

Я в Си делал виртуальную таблицу. Создал массив указателей на функции. И вызываю по коду. Для вашего примера примерно так:

```
enum class MsgCode {
  Type1,
  Type2,
  Type3,
  Type4
};

typedef void (*functype)(void*);

extern functype virtTable [ ] ;

void data_reseive(int msg_type, void* msg_data) {
  functype f = virtTable [ msg_type ] ;
  f ( msg_data ) ; }
```

Для каждого типа отдельная функция :

```
void virtfunc1 ( void * msg_data ) {
  MsgType1 msg;
  msg . process( msg_data ); }
```

Адреса функций надо будет где-то проставить :

```
functype virtTable [ ]  = { virtfunc1 , virtfunc2 ,
  virtfunc3 , virtfunc4 } ;
```

*[KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1304176/288358) примерно похожее показал. Но у меня Си стиль.*

Comment: У Вашего кода есть один фатальный недостаток. Он совершенно не обрабатывает ситуацию, когда индекс (тип сообщения) будет заоблачный. А так вполне.

Comment: Я вот щас выскажу еще одну крамольную мысль: функции надо ставить не *где-то*, а непосредственно при инициализации, и саму таблицу делать `constexpr`.

Comment: @AlexGebe, наверно я недостаточно подробно описал пример, там необходимы именно классы, потому что обработка производится множеством внутренних методов и с использованием внутренних переменных.

Comment: Не понимаю, где у вас классы. В вашем примере просто по-другому работа представлена. Добавьте точку. `msg . process_msg( msg_data);`

Comment: Я не люблю `constexpr`. Нравиться Lisp/JS стиль, с функциональным программированием. @user7860670

Comment: Заоблачный тип это пользовательский ( не в библиотеке )? Или из другого файла? Если из другого файла, то это решается присваиванием указателей на функции отдельной функцией инициализации. @KoVadim

Comment: я написал "заоблачный индекс" - то есть, индекс за пределами массива. Один маленький if решил бы все это.

Answer (score 0):

Так сделать не получится, поскольку Ваш тип данных `MsgType` зависит строго от того, какие данные были получены
На крайняк можно написать какой-нибудь класс, инкапсилурующий внутри себя все эти проверки и скрывающий реализацию выведения типа `MsgType`, но реализация, которая у Вас, на самом деле не является костыльной, можно и так оставить.

Comment: А нельзя задать синонимы типов, которые будут выводиться через значения переменной?

Comment: @Максим, не совсем понял, что ты хочешь, можешь немного уточнить?